# Unix Variables Inheritance Usage

Tags: unix

```
{
 set GAME=CRICKET"
 if(fork()=0)
 {
  set GAME="FOOTBALL"
  echo $GAME
  }
 sleep(5);
 echo $GAME
}
```

My question is that GAME is inherited to child and changed.
Now what happened to the GAME in Parent? Is it still unchanged to "CRICKET"?

Comment: Why ask "what will happen when I run this code" - just run it yourself and see!

Comment: I can't catch what language is used here, but if you pretend it's C, the answer is "yes, it's still unchanged".

Comment: @Netch: Thanks. Actually my quest regarding variable inheritance in unix(not depends on language).Child Process inherits the variable and change it.Now variable value should not be changed in Parent Process(Guess it simple logic).

Comment: I could guess there are weird languages which keep environment in a shared place:), but all runtimes known to me separate it between processes and doesn't copy values from children to their parent. If one needs to return value, the latter should be placed somewhere and then explicitly reused. E.g. my SuSE desktop uses this for changing CWD inside Midnight Commander by replacing direct mc call with a shell function which gets the last mc's directory and applies it.

Answer (score 1):

Unix environment variables are specific to a process.

When you fork a process, the child gets a copy of the parent's environment.

Any changes the child makes will be to its copy and have no effect on the parent's environment variables.